# How give number to listview items in android

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android . I have an application working with listview and i want to number each  list view item.
Like,

1  list item

2  list item

3  list item

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
private OrderDbManager orderDbManager;


private ListView listView;

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

final String[] from = new String[] {  OrderDbHelper.FOOD_NAME,
        OrderDbHelper.QUANTITY, OrderDbHelper.PRICE };

final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvFoodName, R.id.tvItemQuantity, R.id.tvItemPrice };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    orderDbManager = new OrderDbManager(this);
    orderDbManager.open();

    final Cursor cursor = orderDbManager.fetch();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));  

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                     listView.addHeaderView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_header,listView, false));
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
  public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
   String[] from,int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
        TextView txt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSlNo);
        txt.setText(position + 1);

        return convertView;
    }

   }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSlNo"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFoodName"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text=""/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItemQuantity"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItemPrice"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text=""/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

i want to set numbering in  tvSlNo.
please help

Comment: Post your adapter please.

Comment: i am using SimpleCursorAdapter, and not have any other adapter class

Comment: You need to write your own adapter to populate your list, so that you've more control over your list. There are plenty example over internet.

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() method of your listViewAdapter simply use the position variable  and set it on your TextView. You may need to add 1 to the position since it starts with 0. So use (position+1) and then set it to your TextView

Answer (score 0):

Though this question may be too late but for other reference purposes.
Check where you have this code: `txt.setText(position + 1)`;
you are close to your solution. You just have to typecast `position + 1` to `String` since `setText()` only take `String` alone.